# Please show an experiment showing the validity of superposition principle of charges?

Tags: forces, experimental-physics, electric-fields, charge, superposition

I have read in several websites that the superposition principle of electric force has been checked empirically.

Can anyone refer/show an experiment (having easy/difficult configurations of charges) showing its validity?

Answer (score 1):

We have good evidence that all (stable) matter is made of positive nuclei, which are effectively point charges, and negative electrons, which can in rare cases have extended or non-local wavefunctions but when bound to nuclei act as point charges as well.

Therefore every experiment with a macroscopic surface or volume distribution of charge is a test of the principle of superposition of charges. This includes the functioning of capacitors. You are quite probably reading this post while holding in your hand an electrical device where billions of field-effect transistors spend most of their time in a charged but non-conducting state, acting as capacitors. Those devices generally contain a smaller number (thousands or hundreds) of macroscopic capacitors as well.

For that matter, the absence of electric fields near neutral atoms (made of opposite charges), and the way that electric fields are modified by neutral dielectric materials, are also tests of the superposition principle for charges and fields.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know experiments that were specifically designed for testing the superposition principle. Maybe you need to check literature of the early days, earlier than 1800 I think.

I think people believe since Maxwell's Equations are linear, they require superposition principle. Thus any experiment confirms Maxwell's Equations are thought as also confirms the superposition principle.